# Configuration Options for embedded YouTube Videos

Tags: html, embed, videos

I have some embedded You tube videos on my blog and I have a question about configuration as they are on static pages.

Is there code or a WP plugin solution to  make an embedded You Tube video to return to the "Play prompt" position when a video ends.  Currently when a video ends on my site it promotes other Youtube material.  Refreshing (manually)the screens brings it back to "Play prompt" but I would like to do this automatically.

Comment: Append `&rel=0` to the URL to not show _suggested videos_. The _reset to start position_ feature, however, seems not to exist. I only found someone else [asking for it](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-smart-youtube-pro-reset-video-after-playing?replies=1).

Comment: How exactly are you embedding them? Copy/paste from the *sharing* URL, or WP internal oEmbed, or other method? AFAIK, rewinding the vid requires using YT API.